# Bitstream-Charter parenthesis size: text vs. math mode

Tags: fonts

I like the look of Bitstream-Charter; however, the parentheses are larger in math mode than in text, which I find unattractive.

A MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
The mass as a function of time ($M(t)$).
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image: different sized parenthesis]

Is there a workaround to get the text parentheses to be the same size as those in math mode?

Comment: Welcome! There is also `XCharter` but it doesn't seem much different, even with the scaling option recommended in the documentation.

Comment: The parentheses in the `mathdesign` math font for Charter are apparently badly designed. `:-(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @egreg, the parentheses in the math font for charter used by `mathdesign` appear to be the issue. Interestingly, the `utopia` font option in `mathdesign` behaves similarly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
The mass as a function of time ($M(t)$).
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

I corrected the problem for Bitstream-Charter by replacing the delimiters with the appropriate characters in the `mdbch` font.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{bch}{T1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{bch}{'050}{largesymbols}{"00}%
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathopen}{bch}{'051}{largesymbols}{"01}%
}

\begin{document}
The mass as a function of time ($M(t)$).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your code so the parentheses are really the same

Comment: Thank you @egreg! I didn't realize there was more than one version of the normal bitstream charter font. Looks great!

Comment: Yes, the family name is `mdbch`